# Parsing array with {"Name": String, "Value": String} structure in Swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, parsing, codable, swift-structs

I need to parse in Swift a data structure similar to this (based on a JSON):

```js
[
  {
   "Name": "uniquename",
   "Value": "John"
  }, 
  {
   "Name": "locale",
   "Value": "UK"
  }, 
]
```

I stored this node in a `struct` like this

```swift
struct Rowset : Decodable {
  var row: LoggedUserSession

  init(loggedUser: [LoggedUserSession]){
    self.row = loggedUser[0]
  }

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey{
    case row = "Row"
  }
}
```

I prepared a similar `struct` to all the data I need to extract from the array but I don't know how to iterate on that and return the value when the name string match my case.

```swift
struct LoggedUserSession : Decodable {
  var username: String;
  var locale: String;


  init(username: String, locale: String) {
    // In JS I would embedd an iterator here and return the values 
    self.username = username
    self.locale = locale
  }

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case username = "uniquename"
    case locale = "locale"
  }
}
```

Comment: The structs are not related to the JSON at all. *similar to* is more confusing than helpful.

Comment: Do you have an array of `[LoggedUserSession]` and want to filter the array? or need help with the parsing, The question is pretty confusing.

Comment: First do pershing `LoggedUserSession` and then  `Rowset `.

Comment: @vadian the first block of code is a valid JSON.

Comment: @Cœur I didn't assert that the JSON is invalid. The keys don't match the struct members.

Comment: @vadian you're right I'll edit the post to make it more understandable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are saying correctly, you want to parse an array of `LoggedUserSession` JSONs into a swift array of `LoggedUserSession`s. If that's the case, then you're almost there.

For completeness, I'm going to interpret the JSON you posted as follows so that it is valid:

```
{"loggedUserSessions":
  [
    {
     "uniquename": "John",
     "locale": "UK"
    }
  ]
}
```

Your `LoggedUserSession` object is implemented correctly, so now all you need is the array parsing part. You can do that with the following struct:

```swift
struct SessionList: Decodable {

  let sessions: [LoggedUserSession]

}
```

Calling this with `JSONDecoder` and your JSON data should serialize your list into an array that you can access via the `SessionList`'s `sessions` property.